# When I type the tab key, I want a tab, and when I type the whitespace key, I want a whitespace. How can I ensure that?

Tags: whitespace, tabs

In the fundamental mode, when I type the tab key, sometimes I got a tab and sometimes 4(?) whitespaces. When does which happen?

When I type the tab key, I want a tab, and when I type the whitespace key, I want a whitespace. How can I ensure that?

Comment: disable indent tabs mode. `C-q TAB` => TAB, `TAB` => whitespaces

Comment: `(keymap-global-set "C-i" 'self-insert-command)` is probably enough. `TAB` is normally bound to `indent-for-tab-command` (in the global key map), which is responsible for the behavior you see. Disabling `indent-tabs-mode` as @shynur suggests, makes it so that no `TAB`  characters are inserted for indentation, only spaces, and you can still insert a literal `TAB` character as he shows. That might be enough for your purposes, but it certainly doesn't do what you asked: "When I type the tab key, I want a tab". The keymap setting does that.

Comment: I should probably have said that redefining the key in the global map is enough *unless* you enable some minor mode that redefines it differently. See [Active keymaps](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Active-Keymaps.html) in the Elisp manual for more info.

Comment: What do you mean by "the whitespace key"?

Answer (score 1):

Set both `indent-tabs-mode` and `indent-line-function`.

```
(setq indent-tabs-mode t 
      indent-line-function 'indent-to-left-margin)
```

Note that `indent-tabs-mode` is a buffer-local variable and `indent-line-function` is not.

You can see how `makefile-mode` (in `make-mode.el`) do it to ensure that hitting TAB actually inserts tabs in Makefile.

EDIT: you can also use `(indent-tabs-mode)` instead of `(setq indent-tabs-mode t)`.  Note that using `setq` way might not trigger `indent-tabs-mode-hook`.

Comment: Does `(setq *-mode t)` make sense? IIRC, you need to call `*-mode` manually.

Comment: (define-minor-mode indent-tabs-mode
  "Toggle whether indentation can insert TAB characters."
  :global t :group 'indent :variable indent-tabs-mode)
we can do that on indent-tabs-mode because of `:variable indent-tabs-mode`

Comment: I don't think that’s the reason. Almost every mode declares such a variable implicitly. This minor mode variable is defined in C code, so perhaps it is a pseudo mode. Anyway, it is better to call to enable it, IMO.

Comment: Most mode does not have such variable, only the function. Yeah, I think that's a
special case here. Because there are no codes run when we enable/disable
`indent-tabs-mode`, so it's equivalent as setting the variable directly. Well, I
actually do not think too much before you brought up haha. I just replicate what
makefile-mode does.

Comment: indent-tabs-mode-hook might not be run though.

Comment: Most minor modes are defined using `define-minor-mode` and that defines a control variable by default. Hence I expect that most minor modes *do* have such a variable. `C-h f define-minor-mode` says: `This defines the toggle command MODE and (by default) a control variable
MODE (you can override this with the :variable keyword, see below).` It may be that the mode can be turned on by setting its control variable to `t` but that's not the recommended way: many modes do other things on enablement and setting the variable will not work for them. So it is good practice to use the mode function ...

Comment: ... to enable a minor mode: that way you don't have to remember whether the variable is enough for each particular mode. See [Conventions for writing minor modes](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Minor-Mode-Conventions.html) in the Emacs Lisp Reference manual for more details. You *could* customize the variable since modes that need more work provide a `:set` function that `Customize` uses to do the extra work.

Comment: I was very surprised by this answer, but the NEWS for 28.1 explains: "'indent-tabs-mode' is now a global minor mode instead of just a variable." That seems useful for toggling it interactively, but I don't think anyone should ever depend on the associated mode hook running, as (for obvious reasons) the traditional way to set this has always been directly changing the variable.

Comment: I'm also perplexed that it's a *global* minor mode for an automatically-buffer-local variable... that seems like a recipe for confusion!  I presume it works in practice with the 'global' mode being treated as on or off depending on which buffer is current when you call the function -- but that's the expected behaviour for a buffer-local minor mode rather than a global one, so it's really not intuitive.